# Why is my ngFor not working. I am very new with angular please be patient

Tags: angular

I am trying to display all items and cannot seem to get it to work

```
             <tr *ngFor="let item of items">
              <td>
                {{items.subject}}
              </td>
              <td>
                {{items.grade}}
              </td>
              <td>
              </td>
            </tr>
```

Comment: What is not working? You must at least have `{{item.subject}}` in singular, same for the next line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using item.subject instead of items? eg:

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of items">
            <td>{{item.subject}}</td>
            <td>{{item.grade}}</td>
            <td>
            <a class="btn btn-sm btn-danger text-white ml-1"
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that an array exists with the name "items".

In HTML instead of using `{{items.subject}}` use `{{item.subject}}`. Items is the array and `let item of items` in a for loop states to show each object one by one from the array until the array is complete. So your code would be:

```
 <tr *ngFor="let item of items">
          <td>{{item.subject}}</td>
          <td>{{item.grade}}</td>
        </tr>
```